# How can I do something like this in a template?: {{userScores.{{currentUserId}}.[0].score}}

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

This is working for me, but it is hard coded:
`{{userScores.KxXJYDLvCvjk9nLwo.[0].score}}`

I want to use Meteor.userId() in place of the hard coded id.

How can I do that?

Of course, this doesn't work;
`{{userScores.Meteor.userId().[0].score}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly in Blaze, you'll need a helper, ex:

```
{{score0}}
```

js:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  score0() {
    return this.userScores[Meteor.userId()][0].score;
  }
});
```